# Noisy ffmpeg video slideshow from images with looseless sound

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I would play wav audio and show lyric text on TV screen from dvd/bd player. I create [png file from lyric.txt](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28018)
and make video

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i lyric.png -i audio.wav -vcodec libxvid -acodec copy -y -shortest video.avi
```

but video.avi is noisy. Seems text clear, but like in night sky with flickered stars.

Can I ajust ffmpeg parameters? Do encode monochrome jpg with best results? Key frames every 12 are too fast?

By the way, libxvid only suits with wav audio on my sony bd player to be compatible/playable from dvd/bd.

Comment: You may want to use a constant quality parameter such as '-q:v 3'. If the quality is not enough, increase it up to 1. If the file size is too big, increase it up to 6.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Eli, your answer.

I've made some statistics on

- Crazy.wav 53k
- Crazy.txt  2k

with different -q:v parameters

- 6 - 120k (from monochrome picture - 115k)
- 16 - 80k (from monochrome picture - 91k)
- 24 - 73k (poor quality with video bit rate = 500kbs )
- 31 - 69k (very poor quality )

By the way. I've recompress video.avi with virtualdub.exe on ms windows and get 59k file size with video bitrate=138kbs and key frames every 300 frames insted od ffmpeg every 12 frames.

Added solution:

I've found compatability switch and get good results:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i PICTURE.bmp -i AUDIO.flac -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -shortest VIDEO.mkv
```

- Crazy.flac 34k
- Crazy.mkv 36k